# list all files in all subdirectories, not current directory

Tags: windows, batch

Is there a way to list all files in all subdirectories excluding those in the current directory?

`dir /s /b` lists all files, including those in the current directory. That is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Use Powershell:

```
 Get-ChildItem .\*\*
```

#### Edit:

Above example indeed only gets the 2nd level or directories and not contents of subfolders.

@guest's answer is the better one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName}
```

Comment: +1 Best answer I saw, and it does not use batch-files (and OP did not ask for batch-files, only for being able to do this in batches).

Comment: @Hennes I have a nitpick, please check my updated answer.

Comment: @guest I can't comment on your post, so here. `dir -recurse *\*` list content of the current directory. That's not what OP wants.

Your 2nd PoSh example is right and better than my answer. You can drop the 2nd `foreach` and speed it by doing `Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName}` or really short `ls -Dir | % {ls -rec | select fullname}`

Comment: thank for tips (i actually just crank up powershell in response to your answer). however `dir -recurse *\*` doesn't list current dir files for me, tested on W10 PoSh

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions, which I will try to explain one by one.

**Batch**
1) `for /d %i in (*) do @dir /b /s "%i"`
`(*)` expands to all files in current directory.
`for /d` then loops through all directories, excluding regular files, executing `dir /b /s` for each directory.
Since `for` echos executed commands, `@` is used to suppress the echo.

2) `for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /A:D') do @dir /b /s "%i"`
`'dir /b /A:D'` returns all directories in current directory, with each directory on one line.
`"delims="` instructs `for /f` not to tokenize a line but assign the whole line to `%i`.
`for /f` then loops through all lines, executing `dir /b /s` for each line.

Use `%%i` instead of `%i` in batch file.

**Powershell**
`dir *\*` only returns files in level 2 directories.
`dir -recurse *\*` also returns files in deeper directories but doesn't show empty folder in level 2.

Correct commands which take the same approach to that in **Batch**:
1) `dir | where {$_.PsIsContainer} | foreach {dir -recurse $_} | foreach {echo $_.fullname}`

2) `dir -directory | foreach {dir -recurse $_} | foreach {echo $_.fullname}`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: @David done, correct me if i am wrong, feel free to edit.